# Applescript alter text on clipboard

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator

I have written an AppleScript to automate my work setup and just need the final touch. I copy something to clipboard in my script; I need to edit the text I copied to leave only the last line (preferably without opening an actual text editor application, as this would clutter my workspace) and just paste that line in the Google Chrome browser.

---

In the last step of my script so far I do something causing message text to be output to Terminal. Then I get the text visible in Terminal to be copied to the clipboard as follows:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    tell front window
        set the clipboard to contents of selected tab as text
    end tell
end tell
```

Now I can for example paste it, and it's something like

```
...
[I 15:03:31.259 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /workspace
[I 15:03:31.259 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:03:31.259 LabApp] http://1fw5c518af9:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd
[I 15:03:31.259 LabApp]   or http://88.0.0.1:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd
[I 23:56:47.798 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:56:47.803 LabApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://1fw5c518af9:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd
     or http://88.0.0.1:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd
```

This always ends with text of the format `or *URL*`, e.g. in the above example it would be `or http://88.0.0.1:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd`. This is separated from the line above by a line delimiter plus some trailing white-space before "or".

What I need to do is grab that URL, start a Google Chrome browser and paste it in there.

For opening Google Chrome, it should be simple enough, the following code (from this [tut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAZlFptgEPQ&t=462s)) takes you to Instagram:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate

tell application "System Events"
   key code 37 using command down
   delay 0.5
   keystroke "https://www.instagram.com/instagram"
   delay 1
   key code 36
   delay 1

end tell
```

and literally all I need is something which edits what's on the clipboard to just the `*URL*` (in the case of the above example, just `http://88.0.0.1:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd`). After that I can paste it from the clipboard (where Instagram is typed in, in the tutorial).

---

After trying the lovely answer by @user3439894 below I found the situation is a bit more complicated:

1. there are an unpredictable number of blank lines "" after the final
   link.
2. I'm also wondering whether there may be white-space at the end
   as well

I already know the form of http://88.0.0.1 (it's always consistently this) so is there a way of maybe searching for that and then just grabbing it with the rest of the link that follows? (it would be great to be able to delimit the end by either " " or new-line)

Edit 2:
In case `http://88.0.0.1...` occurs multiple times, we would like to select just **one** of these URLs - they are probably generally the same, but selecting the **last** would be safest.

Comment: @user3439894 done. Sorry, to be honest usually I just open the last link in browser by hand (so I didn't even notice the links above). To be clear, it's a bit unpredictable how much of the past text in terminal will be included, so the most robust solution would just take the last occurrence of `http://88.0.0.1...` as the correct URL. In fact it seems the penultimate URL is also fine (as shown in my copy&paste example now put above) but previous ones may also be included in `contents of selected tab`, depending how large the Terminal screen is.

Comment: I have updated my answer to retrieve the last **URL** starting with `http://88`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need to do is grab that URL, start a Google Chrome browser and paste it in there.

&

> This always ends with text of the format `or *URL*`, e.g. in the above
> example it would be `or http://88.0.0.1:1932/?token=5e6d97b348fsy734gd`. This is separated
> from the line above by a line delimiter plus some trailing white-space
> before "or".

&

> In case `http://88.0.0.1...` occurs multiple times, we would like to
> select just **one** of these URLs - they are probably generally the
> same, but selecting the **last** would be safest.

If what you are trying to do is get the last **URL** that starts with `http://88` from  the *contents* of the *selected tab* of the *front window* in **Terminal**, then here is a way to do it without using the clipboard, and open it in **Google Chrome**, and also do it without having to use **UI Scripting**.

In other words, no need to alter the text on the clipboard or keystroke the **URL** as you can just tell **Google Chrome** what to use for the **URL**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Terminal" to ¬
    set theTextFromTerminal to ¬
        the contents of ¬
            the selected tab of ¬
                the front window ¬
                    as text

set theURL to ¬
    the last paragraph of ¬
        (do shell script ¬
            "grep -o 'http://88.*$' <<< " & ¬
            theTextFromTerminal's quoted form & ¬
            "; exit 0")

if theURL is "" then return
if theURL does not start with ¬
    "http://88." then return

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    delay 1
    if exists front window then
        make new tab at ¬
            end of front window ¬
            with properties {URL:theURL}
    else
        set URL of ¬
            the active tab of ¬
                (make new window) to theURL
    end if
end tell
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: thanks for this fantastic answer. it actually turns out the situation is a little harder: when I try `paragraphs of (the clipboard as text)` I found that there are an unpredictable number of blank lines `""` after the final link. I already know the form of `http://88.0.0.1` (it's always consistently this) so is there a way of maybe searching for that and then just grabbing the rest of the link that follows? (I'm also wondering whether there may be white-space at the end as well -- it would be great to be able to delimit the end by either " " *or* new-line)

Comment: (Note unfortunately `http://1fw5c518af9:1932/...` is a dead link - we need `http://88.0.0.1...`. But it's always 88.0.0.1)

Comment: @Vainmonde De Courtenay, I have updated the _code_ to bypass _the clipboard_ and take the the _contents_ of the _selected tab_ of the _front window_ in **Terminal** and process it with `grep` to retrieve the target **URL** and open it in **Google Chrome**.

Comment: thanks! a last complication: it seems the URL `http://88.0.0.1...` appears more than once in the text copied to clipboard. Currently the output I get from `theURL` (in your script) seems to be `"http://88.0.0.1...http://88.0.0.1..."` as it seems to capture both occurrences -- it would be nice to just get one (ideally the last just in case for some strange reason too much past stuff is copied from Terminal to clipboard).

Comment: I am also not sure if the `grep` you used removes trailing whitespace at the end (I seem to get `"http://88.0.0.1...      "` when I'm experimenting with it) but as you probably recognized I'm not sure that can ever detract from validity as a URL in Chrome. (The link worked anyway)

Comment: thank you, perfect stopgap for this problem and bonus points for not even replacing whatever's on the clipboard